# remove the last occurrence of } from a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to use sed to remove the last occurrence of } from a file.  So far I have this:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)}/\1/' file
```

But this removes as many } as there are on the end of the file.  So if my file looks like this:

```
foo
bar
}
}
}
```

that command will remove all 3 of the } characters.  How can I limit this to just the last occurrence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line. For anything else, just use awk, e.g. with GNU awk for gensub() and multi-char RS:

```
$ cat file1
foo
bar
}
}
}
$
$ cat file2
foo
bar
}}}
$
gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{$0=gensub(/\n?}([^}]*)$/,"\\1","")}1' file1
foo
bar
}
}
$
$ gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{$0=gensub(/\n?}([^}]*)$/,"\\1","")}1' file2
foo
bar
}}
$
```

Note that the above will remove the last } char AND a preceding newline if present as I THINK that's probably what you would actually want but if you want to ONLY remove the `}` and leave a trailing newline in those cases (as I think all of the currently posted `sed` solutions would do), then just get rid of `\n?` from the matching RE:

```
$ gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{$0=gensub(/}([^}]*)$/,"\\1","")}1' file1
foo
bar
}
}

$
```

And if you want to change the original file without manually specifying a tmp file, just use the `-i inplace` argument:

```
$ gawk -i inplace -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{$0=gensub(/}([^}]*)$/,"\\1","")}1' file1
$ cat file1
foo
bar
}
}

$
```

Comment: my only issue here is that I have to redirect the output to a temp file and then copy that over the original file.  I tried to use gawk -i inplace but that broke the awk command.

Comment: Why is using a temp file an issue? Just do `awk '...' file file > tmp && mv tmp file`. nbd...

Comment: @Craig - can `}}}` appear in the input and if so what's the expected output?

Comment: Yes, it could.  The expected output would be }}

Comment: OK, then I just provided a different solution - I was previously removing the line containing the last }, now I'm just removing the last } char (AND optionally a preceding newline if present as I'm guessing that's what you'd want rather than simply removing the char but if that's undesirable, post some more sample input and expected output). I also showed this solution using `-i inplace` rather than an explicit tmp file if that matters.

Answer (score 9):

someone game me this as a solution

```
sed -i '1h;1!H;$!d;g;s/\(.*\)}/\1/' file
```

I'm just not sure it's as good as the above awk solution.

Comment: It's one-pass, works equally well as a pipeline filter, it doesn't need any extra commands to modify a file in-place, and it deletes only the last `}` not the whole line containing it.  So I think it's better.  edit: sed's got the `E` switch to enable more readable RE syntax: `sed -iE '1h;1!H;$!d;g;s/(.*)}/\1/' file`

Comment: @jthill Agree, though it only substitutes the last match with nothing effectively leaving a blank line. `sed -r '1h;1!H;$!d;g;s/(.*)}\n/\1/' file` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @jaypal: Your revision doesn't quite work: try `sed -E '1h;1!H;$!d;g;s/(.*)}\n/\1/' <<<$'a}\nb\n}'` (note that `<<<` invariably appends `\n`, so the effective input _does_ end in `\n`). - I think the reason is that the buffer's _last_ line does _not_ end in `\n`.
If you wanted to trim trailing newlines, you could add `; s/\n+$//`.

Comment: @jaypal I think you might have yielded to the temptation to optimize for the test-case, which I think produced the earlier awk answer too.  The problem says only ~the last }~.

Comment: Try modifying it to do something different (e.g. remove the preceding newline if present in addition to the `}`, or print a msg to stderr if the removal happened, or just about anything else) and that will tell you if it's as good as an awk solution. If your next problem has slightly different requirements or the requirements for this one change - do you want your starting point for a new solution to be a sed script like this as a base to build on or a trivial, readable awk script.

Comment: I've been using sed for 30+ years, I use it almost every day, and I couldn't begin to guess what `1h;1!H;$!d;g` means never mind actually come up with that arcane string of characters as the solution to a problem. sed was invented before awk and so has a ton of language constructs to do things that span input lines that it HAD to be able to do before the mid-1970s when awk was invented. These days (i.e. for the past 40 years!), there's just no need to do any of that since awk was invented and supports multi-line records. Brevity is not a desirable attribute of software, conciseness is.

Answer (score 0):

With a buffer you can modify the file directly:

```
awk  'BEGIN{file=ARGV[1]}{a[NR]=$0}/}/{skip=NR}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;++i)if(i!=skip)print a[i]>file}' file
```

Comment: awk has a buiiltin variable `FILENAME` so you don't need your own `file` variable, and you should probably `close()` the file at the start of the END section before starting the loop to write to it though MAYBE awk does that for you, idk.

Comment: @EdMorton Probably awk does that as `END{}` is already in another context. Practical programming practice would be to close the file for every session (input from arguments) rather than closing the file before another one. As for FILENAME, awk's manual doesn't explicitly say that it would retain its value before entering `END`. If you're concerned about default behaviour like if file would get closed by default, then that's one you should consider as well. Nevertheless that could be used.

Comment: From POSIX standard wrt FILENAME: `Inside an END action the value shall be the name of the last input file processed.`.

Comment: Ok noted. I'd consider using that next time.

Answer (score 0):

thnks to @jthill for remark for the 1 line file issue

```
sed ':a
$ !{N
    ba
    }
$ s/}\([^}]*\)$/\1/' YourFile
```

Need to load the file in buffer first. This does not remove the new line if `}` is alone on a line

Comment: If the file has only one line, this will delete it.  To buffer with branching I'd use `:a;$!{N;ba}`.

Answer (score 0):

When I read "do something with the *last* ...", I think "reverse the file, do something with the *first* ..., re-reverse the file"

```
tac file | awk '!seen && /}/ {$0 = gensub(/(.*)}/, "\\\1", 1); seen = 1} 1' | tac
```