# Replace last occurrence of a character in a field with awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm trying to replace the last occurrence of a character in a field with awk. Given is a file like this one:

```
John,Doe,Abc fgh 123,Abc
John,Doe,Ijk-nop 45D,Def
John,Doe,Qr s Uvw 6,Ghi
```

I want to replace the last space " " with a comma ",", basically splitting the field into two. The result is supposed to look like this:

```
John,Doe,Abc fgh,123,Abc
John,Doe,Ijk-nop,45D,Def
John,Doe,Qr s Uvw,6,Ghi
```

I've tried to create a variable with the number of occurrences of spaces in the field with

```
{var1=gsub(/ /,"",$3)}
```

and then integrate it in

```
{var2=gensub(/ /,",",var1,$4); print var2}
```

but the how-argument in gensub does not allow any characters besides numbers and G/g.

I've found a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005657/remove-the-last-occurrence-of-from-a-file) but wasn't able to adapt the solution to my problem.

I'm fairly new to this so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The awk program: `{n=gsub(/ /," ",$3);newv=n?gensub(/ /,",",n,$3):newv;print newv;}` should work just fine. What lead you to believe that it doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$3=gensub(/(.*) /,"\\1,","",$3)}1' file
John,Doe,Abc fgh,123,Abc
John,Doe,Ijk-nop,45D,Def
John,Doe,Qr s Uvw,6,Ghi
```

Get the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins.

Very well-written question btw!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short `awk`

```
awk '{$NF=RS$NF;sub(" "RS,",")}1' file
John,Doe,Abc fgh,123,Abc
John,Doe,Ijk-nop,45D,Def
John,Doe,Qr s Uvw,6,Ghi
```

### Updated due to Eds comment.

Or you can use the `rev` tools.

```
rev file | sed 's/ /,/' | rev
John,Doe,Abc fgh,123,Abc
John,Doe,Ijk-nop,45D,Def
John,Doe,Qr s Uvw,6,Ghi
```

Revers the line, then replace first space with `,`, then revers again.

Comment: A possible issue with the awk version is that the line will reconstitute itself with the assignment to $NF, which could affect lines with multiples spaces. Something like `John,Doe,Qr.....s Uvw 6,Ghi` would be output as `John,Doe,Qr.s Uvw,6,Ghi` instead of `John,Doe,Qr.....s Uvw,6,Ghi`. (where the dots between `Qr` and `s` are spaces, which otherwise get collapsed in the comment, somewhat ironically).  Of course if that's not an issue for the input it's very nice to avoid the gawk-only gensub and regexes!

Answer (score 0):

a very strange workaround, but only works for last single space :

> i.e. `GA 41  RICO` —> `GA 41 ,RICO`

```
 mawk 'NF < 2 || $NF = substr($0, length($1) + 2)' FS=' [^ ]*$' OFS=,
```

---

```
John,Doe,Abc fgh,123,Abc
John,Doe,Ijk-nop,45D,Def
John,Doe,Qr s Uvw,6,Ghi
```