# bash: how to cut field

Tags: bash, awk

I write a script named `1.sh` as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

some_command | awk '{print $1, $5, $6}'
```

when I execute `./1.sh`, I get the result:

```
abc 10.10.10.10.a 1234
def 11.11.11.11.b 5678
ghi 12.12.12.12.c 9012
```

Now I want to make such an output:

```
abc 10.10.10.10 a 1234
def 11.11.11.11 b 5678
ghi 12.12.12.12 c 9012
```

which means that I need to deal with the `$2`.

I'm a newbie on bash so I don't know how I can get this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace last occurrence of a character in a field with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649114/replace-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-field-with-awk)

Comment: With sed: `sed -E 's/.([^.]*)$/ \1/' file`

Comment: @Cyrus  how to use `sed` in `awk`?

Comment: @Cyrus, sir, would like to request you if you could explain here how `sed` is matching from last`.` to till end will be grateful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your awk to take care of it:

```
some_command |
awk 'match($5, /\.[^.]+$/){print $5, substr($5, 1, RSTART-1), substr($5, RSTART+1), $6}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may also help you in same.

```
awk '{match($5,/.*\./);print $1,substr($5,RSTART,RLENGTH-1),substr($5,RSTART+RLENGTH),$6}'  Input_file
```